# Storing and sending session cookies in react native for mobile

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, cookies, react-native, fetch

I'm trying to hook into a traditional web api with my mobile app built in react-native using the fetch api; however, as far as I can discern there is no storing/sending of session cookies with fetch requests in react-native.

My backend is in rails and checks for the current user using

```
  def current_user
    User.find_by_session_token(session[:session_token])
  end
```

Am I going to have to rework the backend or is there a way to pass this cookie with fetch?

Comment: Check this https://github.com/joeferraro/react-native-cookies. But I think it would be better to shift to token based authentication. Check https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper

Comment: @RohanPujari How does this work with get requests?